# How can we place a picture in RichList on right side ? (Blackberry)

Tags: listview, blackberry

In `RichList` we can only place a bitmap image on left side of the list, and it is optional.  but, I really want to place the image on the right side of the list (for example, a "arrow.png" to look like a list).

I have searched a lot but let me know how can I place a image in a `RichList` on the right side.

Comment: I know you'd prefer to use `RichList` for this, but if you find you can't easily do it, writing your own list, where you control the layout, isn't too difficult.  [Here's one example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ListField-row-with-images-and-text/m-p/227993)

Comment: Yeah you got it right. I tried the custom list to but I don't know its just not working for me. And I'm using RichList in many places in my app and now I don't want to change the structure of the app. So I would prefer if I get the solution for RichList.